# PDOExceptionMessage:could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql

I have just started learning PHP and Mysql and I have a problem when I run php file.

[image]

> *error :could not find driver*

This is version that I am using:

[image]

I tried to follow answers of question that similar but still can not solve the problem.

Comment: So, if php cannot find a driver - it means there is no one.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a simple typographical error in your code. You defined your DSN with the string `msql:dbhost=localhost...`
But you should use `mysql:dbhost=localhost...`

See http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php for reference docs on the MySQL DSN format.

You have installed `php-pdo` but you might also need either `php-mysql` or `php-mysqlnd` (prefer the latter).

You can check by running `php -i | less` to give a lengthy report of all the extensions currently installed. Look for the "PDO" section, and confirm that the mysql driver is among the drivers installed:

```
PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => sqlite, mysql, sqlite2
```

If it does, it should be followed by a "pdo_mysql" section. Mine looks like this:

```
pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Id: 731e5b87ba42146a687c29995d2dfd8b4e40b325 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

If you don't have the `pdo_mysql` section, you should install the corresponding yum package for it:

```
sudo yum install php-mysqlnd
```